# finite groups $G$ such that any two commuting elements of $G$ lie in some cyclic subgroup of $G$

Tags: finite-groups

If $n$ is odd, the symmmetry group of a regular $n$ gon (also called a dihedral group) has the property that given two commuting elements $a,b$ it follows that $a,b$ lie in a cyclic subgroup. [This includes an element commuting with its inverse, since $a^{-1}$ is a positive power of $a$ in a finite group.] Cyclic groups also (trivially) have this property. 
I also found that the eight element quaternion group has this property.

I'm wondering if there are other finite groups with this property. Thanks for any feedback/references.

Comment: In any such group, centralizers of elements are cyclic. See [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128841/classification-of-groups-in-which-the-centralizer-of-every-non-identity-element)

Comment: (Given that my prior comments were no longer applicable, I would have welcomed a ping to alert me so I could remove them)

Comment: Let me partially retract the second comment: if centralizers of elements are cyclic, then you clearly have this property. But I am not 100% certain of the converse just now.

Comment: Duh; the quaternions of course show that you can have the property and not have all centralizers cyclic, since the centralizer of $-1$ is $Q_8$.